# Need to Add the Count in Select

Tags: php, mysql

The following query allows me to count the Type of class a student takes.

```
SELECT student_schedule.Grade, LEFT(student_schedule.Course,2) AS 'Type',  
COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM student_schedule
GROUP BY Type, Grade
ORDER BY Grade, Type
```

The result is:

[image]

I would now like to find the ratio for each Type by Grade. The fourth column after Count would be  (303+529+50 or 882) for all rows of Grade 7 and (719+139+15 or 873) for Grade 8. I need a SUM in my SELECT statement I think. To clarify, the fourth column would be 882 for Grade 7 and 873 for Grade 8 in every row for that grade. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "GROUP BY Type, Grade" kinda prevents you from grouping further ("GROUP BY Grade")... One option would be to fetch results and iterate through the records to add Counts by Grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   o.Grade as 'Grade',
   LEFT(student_schedule.Course,2) AS 'Type',  
   COUNT(*) AS 'Count',
   COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student_schedule as i WHERE i.Grade = o.Grade) as 'ratio'
FROM student_schedule as o
GROUP BY Type, Grade
ORDER BY Grade, Type
```

Comment: Success. Thanks for the quick solution. Awesome.

Comment: Glad to help @user3258571

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query for your requirement

```
SELECT t.Grade,t.Type,t.Count,sum(t.Count) from
(SELECT student_schedule.Grade AS 'Grade', LEFT(student_schedule.Course,2) AS 'Type',  
COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM student_schedule
GROUP BY Type, Grade
ORDER BY Grade, Type) as t
GROUP BY t.Count
```